# Jquery else if is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm making this login system and i'm trying to make multiple usernames and passwords.

The following code from `if (username == "ErikHekman")` to the first `Else if`

```
var login = function()
{
    var username = $('#usrname').val();
    var password = $('#pssword').val();

    if (username == "ErikHekman")   //  Username = ErikHekman
                                    //  Password = HekmanErik
    {
        if (password == "HekmanErik") // Als username & password gelijk zijn aan elkaar dan >>
        {
            $('#alert').html('');

            $('#login-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Login succesfully');
            $('#redirecting-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Redirecting');
            setTimeout("window.location='http://google.nl'",1500);
        }

        else // Als username klopt maar niet het juiste wachtwoord dan >>
        {
            $('#alert').html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Wrong password');
        }

    }

    else // Als username niet klopt dan >>
    {
        $('#alert').html("Username not registered");
    } // CODE voor ErikHekman

    else if (username == "Hekman")  //  Username = Hekman
                                    //  Password = Erik
    {
        if (password == "Erik") // Als username & password gelijk zijn aan elkaar dan >>
        {
            $('#alert').html('');

            $('#login-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Login succesfully');
            $('#redirecting-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Redirecting');
            setTimeout("window.location='http://google.nl'",1500);
        }

        else // Als username klopt maar niet het juiste wachtwoord dan >>
        {
            $('#alert').html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Wrong password');
        }

    }

    else // Als username niet klopt dan >>
    {
        $('#alert').html("Username not registered");
    } // CODE voor Hekman

}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: you can't follow an "else" with an "else-if", else must come last

Comment: well, one thing that is wrong is using JS as a username/password system...

Comment: A login system in javascript is not very safe since everyone can look into your code

Comment: I know this isn't that safe but it's a school project and it's just an exercise for learning Jquery but thanks for the comment! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have  a `else` before a `else if` and that is wrong.

```
  var login = function()
    {
        var username = $('#usrname').val();
        var password = $('#pssword').val();

        if (username == "ErikHekman")   //  Username = ErikHekman
                                        //  Password = HekmanErik
        {
            if (password == "HekmanErik") // Als username & password gelijk zijn aan elkaar dan >>
            {
                $('#alert').html('');

                $('#login-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Login succesfully');
                $('#redirecting-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Redirecting');
                setTimeout("window.location='http://google.nl'",1500);
            }

            else // Als username klopt maar niet het juiste wachtwoord dan >>
            {
                $('#alert').html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Wrong password');
            }

        }


        else if (username == "Hekman")  //  Username = Hekman
                                        //  Password = Erik
        {
            if (password == "Erik") // Als username & password gelijk zijn aan elkaar dan >>
            {
                $('#alert').html('');

                $('#login-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Login succesfully');
                $('#redirecting-alert').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Redirecting');
                setTimeout("window.location='http://google.nl'",1500);
            }

            else // Als username klopt maar niet het juiste wachtwoord dan >>
            {
                $('#alert').html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Wrong password');
            }

        }

        else // Als username niet klopt dan >>
        {
            $('#alert').html("Username not registered");
        } // CODE voor Hekman

    }
```

Comment: @RemcovanderNiet check my code, I deleted your "extra" `else`, you can use my code, it works fine. In the line 17 you have an extra `else` and I don't.

Comment: @RemcovanderNiet i see you are a new user, just a tip, if you are ok with my answer, click on check mark to mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to programming and found out this website is great for getting help with coding! Thank you very much!